# Can setrawcookie() method accept URL as a value?

Tags: php, url, cookies

Can I pass URL as string to setrawcookie() in PHP ?

For example:

```
setrawcookie('Cookie', 'Owner=me&Website=http://my.website.com')
```

I am asking, because for some reason my cookie in the browser looks like:

> Owner=Me&Website=

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
setrawcookie('Cookie', 'Owner=me&Website=http://my.website.com')
```

To:

```
setrawcookie('Cookie', "Owner=me&Website=http://my.website.com")
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume the issue is tied with the character set.

Encode the cookie value, and decode when retrieving it back.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php